# Raster tiles building extrusion

Tags: maps, mapbox, mbtiles, vector-tiles, mapbox-api-rastertiles

Is there any possible way to extrude all building at a certain zoom level on mapbox using raster tiles or is it a requirement to be using vector tiles for this task?

Currently im assuming this as the example on how to produce 3D building in mapbox requires a source layer of buildings, to my best knowledge this is only possible on a vector tile; can anyone confirm or deny this and show me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to do this I created a docker container using overv/openstreetmap-tile-server and gospatial/tegola, this combination enabled processing of data and storage by openstreetmap-tile-server which would also produce raster tiles and tegola would produce the vector data needed for the building layer to be extruded.